# Use "System.SysUtils" or "SysUtils" in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

In Delphi XE3, it seems that one can use either "System.SysUtils" or "SysUtils", "Vcl.FileCtrl" or "FileCtrl".

I read the article in http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/usingnamespaces_xml.html , it seems the former is called full qualified namespace, while the latter is the generic name. But if i understand correct, one should add statements like:

"Uses System, Vcl", before one can use the units under these namespaces. But I check the codes but cannot find any "Uses System" or "Uses vcl". Why?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are reading old documentation, and reading the wrong topic anyway.

`System` and `Vcl` in this context are actually [Unit Scope Names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unit_Scope_Names), which are *similar* to, but quite different from, [Namespaces](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Namespaces_with_Delphi). Unit Scope Names were introduced in XE2, to allow VCL and FMX to share common unit names under different scopes (`Vcl.Forms` vs `FMX.Forms`, etc). Existing VCL code being migrated to FMX did not (largely) need to be re-written, it could `use` just `Forms`, etc and *magically* pick up the correct scope based on project type. The same does not work with Namespaces.

The reason you don't have to explicitly specify Unit Scope Names in `uses` statements in code is because they are configured at the project level instead, and by default most VCL projects have the `System` and `Vcl` scope names pre-configured.

So, when you `use` just `SysUtils`, `FileCtrl` etc in your code, the compiler checks them against the project's Unit Scope Names and eventually finds `System.SysUtils`, `Vcl.FileCtrl`, etc.