# Find fully qualified unit names quickly?

Tags: delphi, namespaces

I like to use fully qualified unit names in the *Uses* statement as much as possible:

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;
```

but I don't always know this. E.g. after introducing the `Min()` function, I have no idea what the fully qualified name for the *Math* unit is, so I just add that

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Math;
```

Is there a trick to quickly find the fully qualified name?

<sup>Related: [Namespaces in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100160/namespaces-in-delphi), [Use "System.SysUtils" or "SysUtils" in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296417/use-system-sysutils-or-sysutils-in-delphi)</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just hover over the unit name, e.g. `Math`, in the uses statement with the mouse cursor.
 A tooltip with the fully qualified unit name (`System.Math`) should appear.

Answer (score 1):

(*Answering my own question with one trick I found, but maybe there are others*)

Just add the 'unqualified name',

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Math;
```

... then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Click</kbd> the new name. This opens the Delphi source file with the cursor positioned on the *unit* statement:

```
{*******************************************************}
{                                                       }
{           CodeGear Delphi Runtime Library             }
{                                                       }
{ Copyright(c) 1995-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc. }
{              All rights reserved                      }
{                                                       }
{ Copyright and license exceptions noted in source      }
{                                                       }
{*******************************************************}

unit System.Math;
```

Comment: I've found it is more fast to use `Ctrl + Enter key` combo to open file at cursor. Sometimes, when you write code there is no time to switch between mouse and keyboard. [There you can find more interesting HotKeys](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Default_Keyboard_Shortcuts) ;)

Comment: does this work if you have only the DCU file and not the full source code?

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout, no this will not work if you don't have source `*.pas`-files. And IDE will say to you: `Unable to locate file "XXX.pas"`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

Use DelphiDabblers [Unit2NS](https://delphidabbler.com/software/unit2ns.html) tool.

*Unit2NS is a little tool for Delphi programmers to find the namespace(s) that a unit belongs to.*